# Vala - How to create a HTTP request with Soup?

Tags: linux, httprequest, gtk3, vala

I'm a bit lost with vala docs.
Im trying to do a POST request to my AJAX service with soap lib, but no luck. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
string url = "http://myservice/ajax.php";          

// create an HTTP session
var session = new Soup.Session ();
var message = new Soup.Message ("POST", url);

//Setting params and request
var params = "action=call&method=get_monuments";    
Soup.MemoryUse buffer = Soup.MemoryUse.STATIC;  

//(Error here - Line 73)
message.set_request ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", buffer, params, params.length);

// send the HTTP request and wait for response
session.send_message (message);
stdout.write(message.response_body.data);
```

Compiler drops following error:

```
/home/ibsenleo/valaprojects/test/main.vala(73,73): Error: Argument 3: Cannot convert from `string' to `uint8[]'
```

I'm sure is something about request parameters and the data type, but i couldn't find some useful examples.

Comment: The error message is very clear. You have an unresolvable type-missmatch.

Answer (score 4):

[`Soup.Message.set_request`](http://valadoc.org/libsoup-2.4/Soup.Message.set_request.html)'s third argument is a `uint8[]`, not a `string`, and there is no fourth argument.  You probably want something like

```
message.set_request ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", buffer, params.data);
```

See [`string.data`](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/string.data.html).

Comment: Great!, that was the key. Pretty obvious for some, but for me sometimes is a bit cryptic. Im starting to program in vala and usually got lost into de documentation. Thanks a lot.